# How to overload << cout for a template class?

Tags: c++, linked-list, double, overloading, cout

We were taught how to overload cout the other day for our program to cout but I don't know how to make it output everything.

```
 template <NODETYPE>
 friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &, List<NODETYPE>& );


template<typename NODETYPE>
ostream &operator <<(ostream& output, List<NODETYPE>& value)
{ 
    output << value;
    return output;
}
```

However, my program has at least 5 objects to output and two of them are doubles. I get an error for that that says 'double is not a valid type for a template constant parameter'

My two problems are: How do I output all my objects and not just the first object; and how do I get the double to output. Please and thanks!

EDIT: HUGE EDIT:::

Okay, I realized I was doing something wrong, rearranged my header, and source files.

And then I also realized that missing my lecturer's class was one of the biggest mistakes I've ever made. My next error, was giving you all my assumptions, and not the information that I assumed from.

In my assignment, it says: •    Write an assignment operator and a friend function to output the linked list.

in almost every other line of my main function(a function that I'm not allowed to alter), there is a cout:

```
List<int> Li, Li2, Li3;
List<double> Ld, Ld2;
```

These are my objects. And all my couts look something like this:

```
  cout << "Ld is: " << Ld << endl;
```

After rearranging my header and source files, I got this error:
"no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<<[with_Traits = std::char_traits] (((std::basic_ostream>&)(& std::cout)), ((const char*) 'Ld is"))<

I get that for every single cout statement I have. It's more information than Ld exit status is 1 or whatever, so I'm going from this.

I'm still not fully keen on using this ostream overload function, so any help appreciated and thank you so much for your time!

EDIT::--

I've put almost all my code in this post: [collect2: Ld returned 1 exit status build make error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509187/collect2-ld-returned-1-exit-status-build-make-error)

If someone could help me with the overload that'd be great, because I think it's the only problem I've got left so I can figure out everything else.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are those two declarations *exactly identical*, or did I forget my reading glasses?

Comment: So bad, haha they're the same..my bad..I'll edit it

Comment: I don't understand how the error is connected to the declaration/definition above.

Comment: The declaration (i.e. the first piece of code) should be changed to `template <typename NODETYPE>` (i.e. the `typename` is missing). Is that the problem?

Comment: Definition of operator leads to infinite recursion, no?

Comment: @ForEveR Ahh.. that's right. But I am still surprised about the error message.

Comment: When i had the template <typename NODETYPE> I got an error because it's in my class that already has the same template <typename NODETYPE>

Comment: @Nelliel Still, you need `typename`. If you have a double definition, you need to resolve that separately.

Comment: Coming to thing of it, there may a problem in how you use the `friend` declaration. The `friend` declaration is either unnecessary, or it must be part of a class definition.

Comment: crap.. okay, well I put in the typename... I got the error: shadows template parm 'class NODETYPE'.. Isn't there another way?

Comment: And oh..interesting because my lecturer said we had to use the friend function, so it must be something I'm doing..hmm

Comment: Have you put the ``ostream operator<<`` in a header included by main?

Comment: Yes, I have.. List.h is included in my main.cpp

Comment: I suggest boiling it down to some simpler class template with ``ostream`` operator. There is way too much code to address the problem you claim to be having.

Comment: Well actually, after I fixed the problem that I had in the other post(which apparently, I was missing my getNewNode definition), the function now runs. It just doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform some kind of iteration over the `List<NODETYPE>`, printing out each node. Otherwise you have an infinite recursion, with the operator calling itself.

This example prints out the elements separated by a single space, in a single line. I have omitted the details of the iteration mechanism because I don't know your `List` interface.

```
template<typename NODETYPE>
ostream &operator <<(ostream& output, const List<NODETYPE>& value)
{ 
   for ( node in value) // pseudocode iteration
   {
     output << node << " ";
   }
   return output;
}
```

This assumes there is an `ostream& operator<<` for the node types, if not you have to provide that too. Also, note I pass the list by `const reference`. This has many advantages, one of them being you can pass temporary objects.

Concerning the `friend` declaration, you also need `template<typename T>` there, but it isn't clear you need the operator to be `friend` in the first place. Lists typically provide access to their elements in their public interface.

Comment: Well, in the main function, this is what happens (and I can't change this):
List<int> Li, Li2, Li3;
List<double> Ld, Ld2;

Comment: Aside from that, my header is pretty much what it should be. I just keep getting a shadow error because of the template<typename NODETYPE>

Comment: @Nelliel just follow what I proposed in my answer, and probably drop the `friend`.

Comment: @Nelliel if the friend declaration is giving you shadowing problems, change `NODETYPE` in it to something else.

Comment: Okay, and will this also output the doubles?

Comment: Right! Okay, so I edited it, (I have to use friend as my lecturer requests it) and would it have been alright that I changed my template<typename NODETYPE> to template<typename OUTPUT> instead? It got rid of the error but, I'm not sure if that worked.

Comment: @Nelliel that sounds right. Try it out. And then comment out the `friend` declaration and see if it still works.

Comment: I just realized my major flaw now. I have no loop. I'm not sure how to run loop for something like this :S and I cant use List like everyone else is telling me to..

Comment: @Nelliel that is the flaw I was intending to highlight in this answer :-) Your list *must* have a means of iteration.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the loop working. I keep getting errors. I've been trying with a while loop >.<

Comment: I edited my OP, is it possible that you could give it a glance?

Comment: Alright, I got it to work more or less, but only one problem: I can't access my private functions. I'm using the friend function, so what else can I try?

Comment: This is the declaration

  template <typename OUTPUT >
  friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &, const List<NODETYPE> & );

This is my definition 


template<typename NODETYPE>
ostream &operator <<(ostream &output, const List<NODETYPE> &li)
{
    ListNode<NODETYPE> *currentPtr = li.firstPtr;

    while(currentPtr != 0)
    {
        output << currentPtr->data;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }

      return output;
}

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>`'s `operator<<` should iterate through each element of type `T` in the list and call `output << element;` on each.

Then, make sure each type `T` that you create a `List<T>` object with also implements an `operator<<` which outputs each of its variables you would like it to, in the format you would like it to, such as `output << "(" << x << "," << y << ")"`. Built-in types already do this, so for example `List<int>` will not require this step.

Answer (score 0):

1) The `friend` declaration is unnecessary, unless the `NODETYPE` you want to use as template argument is a class you defined yourself, *and* the `operator<<` you are defining wants to access any private members of `NODETYPE`. It seems that right now, `NODETYPE` is `double`, so there is no need for a `friend` declaration.

If you have other data types you'd like to use as template arguments, and those other data types are your own classes, put a `friend` declaration *inside* those classes. (This may be true of the `List` type, as described below).

2) Right now, your `operator<<` is recursive. You must (as suggested by the other answers) somehow iterate through the list of `NODETYPE` objects you get:

```
for(List::const_iterator it = value.begin() ; it != value.end() ; ++it)
  output << *it;
```

(The above assumes, your `List` datatype implements `begin()`, `end()` and iterators. You may want to use a different way of iterating through the elements of the `List`. For that, you may actually have to access private members of the `List` data type, in which case you must declare the `operator<<` as a friend template (including `typename`!) inside the `List` class definition.)

Comment: I think your first point applies to `List<NODETYPE>`, not to `NODETYPE` itself.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, it seems the OP is using simple (fundamental) data types for `NODETYPE`. I hope the second point explains how it may be necessary to have a `friend` declaration in the `List` definition.

Comment: What I mean is that the `friend` declaration gives access to `List<NODETYPE>`'s private members, not `NODETYPE`'s.

Comment: Isn't that what the parenthesis after the first, and the explanation at the end of the second point say? Perhaps I need to make the wording clearer.

Comment: After reading this so many times, I finally understand more or less what you're saying (beg pardon, I haven't slept all night working on this program) -- So basically, I need to use a for loop to go through all the objects, but this is the part I really don't understand... How can I make a loop go through my objects? (How do I know how many objects there will be...It's not limited to just the ones in my main fxn at this moment...)